# Javascript regex to strip selective html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to strip all ***(except some)*** html tags from a string using regex. What I am trying currently trying is as follows:

```
var a = "<pre><code><p>This is a <span>test</span></p></code></pre>";
var b = a.replace(/(\<|\<\/)[^\>,p,li,br,b]*\>/ig,"");
```

but b's value is returned as `"<pre><p>This is a <span>test</span></p></pre>"`

It seems any tags that contain even a single instance of [>,p,li,br,b] are not being removed, as here all `pre`, `span` and `p` contains the character `p`. However, I only want to ignore the exact characters in `[^\>,p,li,br,b]`.

The output I am expecting is `"<p>This is a test</p>"`.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You do not use [RegExp to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = "<pre><code><p>This is a <span>test</span></p></code></pre>";
var b = a.replace(/\<(?!\/?(p|li|br|b)[ >])[^>]*\>/ig,"");
```

This regex matches the leading `<` or `</` only if it is not followed by one of the tag names you want to keep `p`, `li`, `br`, `b` (followed by a space or closing `>`, so that it doesn't think `<pre>` is `<p>`).

Then it matches everything up to the closing `>`.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

That said, square brackets `[]` match on single characters, not words - for more information on what yours is doing, see the bottom of this answer.  Instead, you would need to use parentheses `(?:p|li|br|b)` to match words - the `?:` is used to avoid capturing.  Also, the parentheses would occur outside of the square brackets.

Since you're using a negative match you may wish to look into [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); specifically, the section on Positive and Negative Lookbehind.

---

`[^\>,p,li,br,b]` translates to *not `>` and not `,` and not `p` and not `,` and not `l` and not `i` and not `,` and not `b` and not `r` and not `,` and not `b`*.